# Verification of the last char

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to make a field that verifies the last char written down between['A'..'Z'] but don't know why the alert won't show.

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>      
   <label>field</label>
  </p>
  <p>     
   <textarea name="rq" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" onkeyup="MyFunc()">
   </textarea>
  </p>
<script>
    function Myfunc(){
      stc=document.rq.value.charAt(document.rq.value.length-1);
      if(stc.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)<65 || charCodeAt(0)>90){
        alert("false");
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is too little information. Please provide a complete example and explain what exactly "doesn't work". See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify what's your goal of checking `.charCodeAt(0)<=65`

Comment: edited should be clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example, I took you code and change it a little.
You had problem with the `f` in MyFunc

```html
<script language=javascript>
    function MyFunc(){
      var value=document.getElementById("textarea").value;    
      var stc = value.charAt(value.length-1).toUpperCase();
      if(stc.charCodeAt(0)<65 || stc.charCodeAt(0)>90){
        alert("false");
      }
    }
</script>
<textarea name="rq" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" onkeyup="MyFunc()">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new here I will do it now.

Comment: why whenever I reverse the comparison signes like this  `if(stc.charCodeAt(0)>=65 || stc.charCodeAt(0)<=90)` It shows the alert when pressing any key?

Comment: cause look at the values, <=90 || >=65 this is all the numbers

Comment: hmm yeah thx I did this and now working `if(stc.charCodeAt(0)>=65 && stc.charCodeAt(0)<=90)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly are the characters you test. But you are likely to rarely get your alert to be shown, unless the first character of stc is an `"a"`, whose `toUpperCase().charCode` is 65. `'B'` charcode is 66, and so on.

Are you testing for numbers or special characters ? Which is probably not the case since you are "upperCasing" characters.

Comment: I'm trying to verify the last char to see if it's an alphabetic char or other char.

Comment: @medamine. The answer of Alon is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve your problem with regex and just to remind - javascript is case sensitive

```
<html>
<body>     
 <label>field</label>
 <br>
 <script language=javascript>
    function MyFunc(){
      var str = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
      var last_character = str[str.length-1];
      if(last_character.match(/[a-zA-Z]/i)){
        alert("false");
      }
    }
</script>
<textarea name="rq" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" onkeyup="MyFunc()"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it throws an alert if you enters a-z or A-Z or it should do it in other case? then you could can add ! here:  **if(!last_character.match(/[a-zA-Z]/i)){**